# NumberFormatException on Android 9.0 devices, unable to find cause of issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime, numberformatexception

Part of my code is crashing for users only using Pixel/Pixel 2 phones on `Android 9.0`. I've used Android Emulator to test as many situations as possible and have been unable to reproduce the reported `NumberFormatException`.

Here is the code that the crash is referring to:

```
public void onRecieve(...) {
     //...
     int network_pref = Integer.parseInt(getDefaults("network_pref", context));
     //...
}

public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
```

The default value for the preference is "0", the only other option is "1".

[image: runtimeException]

Comment: If you're able to log into your crash reporting platform - log the offending value, and then probably file an issue on the Android issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible that you get default method is returning null, because that's the value you are passing.

You may try this and it may work...

```
public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, "0");
}
```

Comment: This appears to have reduce the number of crash reports I'm getting, however I believe it's something to do with SharedPreferences in a background service. In most scenarios this should fix it for others.